# Property 'select' does not exist on type 'HTMLSelectElement'. Did you mean 'onselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, typescript

I have a jquery code, I want to convert it to pure javascript, but I am getting an error.

How can I solve this issue I tried all the solutions but couldn't fix it.

```
    let categories = $("#myCategories").find('.products');
    let res = categories.select.data;
    console.log(res)

    let categories2 = document.getElementById("myCategories") as HTMLSelectElement;
    let res2 = categories2.select.data;
    console.log(res2)
```

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vewzY.png)

Answer (score 0):

do you want this?

```js
let categories2 = document.getElementById("myCategories");
    let res2 = categories2.value;
    console.log(res2)
```

```html
<select id="myCategories">
<option value="1" >1</option>
<option value="2" selected>2</option>
</select>
```